# Outlook 365: Why do people have two columns, with multiple calendar events for same time?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am completely stumped by this.

This is the calendar for two other people.

What does it mean? They are doing two things at once? (isn't that what Outlook is supposed to prevent?)

[image]

Comment: Outlook doesn’t prevent a user from putting two things on their calendar at the same time.  What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are planning to do two things at once - or are at least scheduled to do two things at once.
Outlook is not supposed to prevent this, but it does ensure that any conflicts in scheduling can be seen. The User has control over what they actually do.